# Adding *1 to addAttributeToSort not working

Tags: mysql, magento, sql-order-by

I'm working within a product collection returning products and trying to order them. The problem is one of my product attributes (I find this out at 90% of the way through my project) is a quantity, i.e. 250, 5000 etc. However, I've just found out that despite these being numbers Magento treats them as strings, so therefore the collection returns the following quantities in this example:

```
50,100,250,500,1000,2000,5000
```

However, `addAttributeToSort('quantity','ASC');` does this:

```
100,1000,2000,250,50,500,5000
```

I've done a `var_dump()` on the collection and ascertained that the values are being treated as strings, hence why this is probably happening. Unfortunately I've got over 6000 products with a lot of custom implementations and configurable products depending on this attribute, so am reluctant to change it. Searching on here I found that adding `ORDER BY 'quantity' *1` does actually perform the sort correctly, however I can't seem to implement this  clause in the standard `addAttributeToSort` function.

If anyone could help me implement this, I've tried `addAttributeToSort('quantity','*1');` but that doesn't work, just errors.

Many thanks

### UPDATE:

Here's the syntax for the query which is generated from the following code:

```
$collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addFieldToFilter('name', array( 'like' => '%' . $stock . '%' ));
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('quantity' *1)); 
count($collection);
```

> `'SELECT 'e'.*, 'link_table'.'parent_id', IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS 'name', 'price_index'.'price', 'price_index'.'tax_class_id', 'price_index'.'final_price', IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS 'minimal_price', 'price_index'.'min_price', 'price_index'.'max_price', 'price_index'.'tier_price' FROM 'catalog_product_entity' AS 'e' INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_super_link' AS 'link_table' ON link_table.product_id = e.entity_id INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_website' AS 'product_website' ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = '1' INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' AS 'at_name_default' ON ('at_name_default'.'entity_id' = 'e'.'entity_id') AND ('at_name_default'.'attribute_id' = '65') AND 'at_name_default'.'store_id' = 0 LEFT JOIN 'catalog_product_entity_varchar' AS 'at_name' ON ('at_name'.'entity_id' = 'e'.'entity_id') AND ('at_name'.'attribute_id' = '65') AND ('at_name'.'store_id' = 1) INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_index_price' AS 'price_index' ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (link_table.parent_id = 3781) AND (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) LIKE '%PCL Labels%')'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I achieved this in PHP via `ksort()`. The database model when implementing any Zend functions was being overridden somewhere and I couldn't afford the time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

try
`$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('quantity' *1));`

Comment: My current query is this, how would I implement the above code within this? `$collection   = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('name', array(
                'like' => '%' . $stock . '%'
            ))->addAttributetoSort('quantity','ASC');`

Comment: just add `->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('quantity' *1))` to the end of your magento collection expression. of course, remove addattributetosort

Comment: or `$collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('name', array( 'like' => '%' . $stock . '%' ));
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('quantity' *1));`

Comment: Note there was a double quotation mark at the end of the query, I removed it now

Comment: My query is now `$collection   = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('name', array(
                'like' => '%' . $stock . '%'
            ))->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('quantity' *1));` which doesn't "error" as such, but doesn't return any results it appears. Is there a way of echo'ing the select? I conventionally use `echo $collection->getSelect();` but since adding your line of code it doesn't recognise this method, I guess as it's already used in the line of code you suggested?

Comment: try counting but do getselect independently 
`$collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldTo‌​Filter('name', array( 'like' => '%' . $stock . '%' )); $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('quantity' *1));
count($collection);`
you can echo select with `$collection->getSelect()->assemble()` . See whats the syntax it produces

Comment: I've updated the original post to reflect the latest status following your code.